# Is there a way to combine an Else with a Catch in Java?

Tags: java

```
 if (condition) {
    try {

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ...
    }

} else {
    throw new ....
}
```

I want to try and combine the two same exceptions being thrown. Is there any way of accomplishing this? Something like

```
if (condition) {

} else/catch {
    throw new ....
}
```

Comment: no, nor should there, since it makes no sense to do so.

Comment: This idea really makes no sense and your question lacks any explanation for your wanting it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I wanted to add the condition to be more restrictive in running the code that potentially throws the exception. However, I still want the exception to be thrown in the case that an actual exception is thrown, or the condition is false.

Comment: Of course it makes sense. Why not? Other languages like C++, Scala or Perl implement much crazier ideas :-) But sorry, there is no such a structure in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
try {
    if (condition) {
        // do something
    } else {
        throw new SomeCustomException();
    }
} catch (SomeCustomException | AnyOtherException e) {
    // do something else
}

....
static class SomeCustomException extends Exception { }
```

If it makes sense, you can throw only the AnyOtherException without creating the custom one.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely not, which is good because there is no reason to do it.
If you want to avoid code duplication consider creating a method that should be called in both `catch` and `else` blocks.

Answer (score 1):

No. Your choices are:

1. Repeat the necessary handling code in the 'catch' and 'else' blocks.
2. Implement a private method to contain that code, and call this method from the 'catch' and 'else' blocks.
3. Add auxiliary variables, see below.

In the case you show, where there is literally one statement in each of the 'catch' and 'else' blocks, choice 1 almost certainly is the better.  As some point of 'repeated code', choice 2 or 3 will become worthwhile.  I tend to use choice 2 if the 'repeated code' is fairly self-contained, choice 3 if it needs a lot of context from the routine I'm working in.

---

```
 boolean good = false;
 if (condition) {
    try {
       ...
       good = true;
    } catch (Exception) {
       ...
    }
 }

if (!good) {
    throw new ....
}
```